# Woocommerce - Hide “add to cart” on free products

Tags: plugins, csv

im using Woocommerce and searching for a way to hide the "Add to cart"-Button on
a single-Product page **IF** the product is for free - I'm making a big CSV-Import and some product-prices are set to zero - i just want to hide the "add to cart" button on these products, so these are not buyable.

already asked this on the support page, but no success

Greets

Comment: Do you have the Code of your `single-product.php`?

Comment: Yes, but i dont think it would help since changes on the single-product.php has no effect on this issue. Somebody told me to "create a new function hooked into init which checks a product price, if it's zero remove the add to cart button using remove_action()"

So yea, im not good at coding and can't do this on my own. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look at the beginning of the add to cart templates in WooCommerce. At the beginning there is a check to determine whether the product is purchasable. Inside the `is_purchasable()` method in the product class is a filter. By default the product is not purchasable if there is no price set at all, but that can be extended to cover products for which the price is set to 0.

```
function wpa_109409_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
    if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
        $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpa_109409_is_purchasable', 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Thanks alot! This was exactly the solution for my problem!

Comment: @helgatheviking, your many answers over here are priceless. I keep finding again and again! thanks!

Comment: You're welcome @peteroak, I'm glad you found them useful. I spend too much time here :) (more at SO now in the WooCommerce tag, but still)

Comment: YAS! I was adding a ridiculous amount of conditionals to template files to check for a proprietary value to see if a user was allowed to purchase a thing. Used this filter instead (which I somehow completely missed) - *SOLVED*! Thanks, Kathy.

Comment: Hello @helgatheviking is it possible to add a product description or message on the page for those specific product when hide to cart ?

Comment: i have find a solution hooking "woocommerce_single_product_summary" with "$product->is_purchasable()"

Comment: For some reason our site was not displaying an add to cart button for a product with price 0.00 so we added this code and now its adding the add to cart button to products that don't have any price entered at all (we would prefer no cart button here) Any suggestions please? add_filter( 'woocommerce_is_purchasable', 'wpa_109409_is_purchasable', 10, 2 ); function wpa_109409_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){ if( $product->get_price() >= 0.00) $purchasable = true; return $purchasable; }

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understood your problem.. woocommerce has an option when you don't put any price, there will be no button at all..
Your product becomes like just a regular gallery/catalog..
Should that's what you're looking for.. perhaps the easiest way would be then to edit your csv file.. just find and replace zeros with empty space..