# remove ad to cart button and view more button if product price is empty

Tags: plugins

Well I need help guys . I want remove cart and view more button id product price is empty .
I am using this code for showing contact us link.

```
    if( empty($product->price) ){
  echo '<a href="' . get_post_permalink(183) . '" class="button product_type_simple ajax_add_to_cart"> Contact us </a>'; 
}
    ?> 
but I want remove view more button when contact us link is showing
```

Answer (score 1):

Add this in function file for hide add to cart button

```
function wpa_109409_is_purchasable( $purchasable, $product ){
if( $product->get_price() == 0 )
    $purchasable = false;
    return $purchasable;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_is_purchasable','wpa_109409_is_purchasable', 10, 2);
```

Visit this link for more detail [Woocommerce - Hide “add to cart” on free products](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/109409/woocommerce-hide-add-to-cart-on-free-products)

Comment: kamleshpal@give me time I will let you knwo what I have to do

Comment: kamleshpal@well add to cart button does not showing but view cart button is still there